# How to call the abstract method from a class which is not in hierarchy in java

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Below is my code. I have the abstract class `Myabatract` which has the method `myMethod` and I have a subclass `MySubClass` in which I have overridden the `myMethod`. In my client class
I have a method `callMethod` from which I want to directly call the `myMethod` of `Myabatract` class is this possible?

```
abstract class Myabatract {

public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("This is from Myabatract");
}

}

class MySubClass extends Myabatract  {
public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("This is from MySubClass");
    super.myMethod();
}
}


class Client{
public void callMethod(){

}
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's defeating the purpose of OOP. If a subclass has overridden the method of its parent, it is saying that that method is only meaningful in the context i have provided. If the subclass needs to use the superclass's implementation of a method, it should properly call ``super`` inside its method override.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anonymous implementation of the `abstract class`. This is particularly easy given the fact that it does not use any `abstract` methods.

```
class Client {
  public void callMethod() {
    Myabatract instance = new Myabatract() { /* nothing to implement*/ };

    instance.myMethod();
  }
}
```

As a user of the `MySubClass` type, you have no way to call the `Myabatract` method because it has been overridden, unless `MySubClass` were to expose it. Your only recourse would be to create another method that exposed the `super` method from within `MySubClass` (or other child implementations).

It's important to note that this will *not* work:

```
class Client {
  public void callMethod() {
    MySubClass instance = new MySubClass() {
      @Override
      public void myMethod() {
        super.myMethod();
      }
    };

    instance.myMethod();
  }
}
```

`super` is the non-anonymous class, `MySubClass`, which means nothing is actually changing. Interestingly, this can be worked around in C++ using the scope resolution operator (`::`).

It's also worth pointing out that you are calling `super.myMethod()` in your implementation of `MySubClass`, which does invoke the `Myabatract` method.